# PHP mktime not working as expected

Tags: php

With my code I'm trying to make the URL go to the previous or next month on a button click based on what is in the current URL.

For example if I have the end of the URL as `index?view=list&month=January&year=2014` then I would want the previous button to go to `index?view=list&month=December&year=2013`. For January it works fine, but when the month is February the previous button equals February and the next button is April.

Previous Button

```
onclick="location.href='?view=list

&month=<?php echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n', strtotime($_GET['month'])) - 1, 1, $_GET['year'])); ?>

&year=<?php echo date("Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n', strtotime($_GET['month'])) - 1, 1, $_GET['year'])); ?>
```

Next Button

```
onclick="location.href='?view=list

&month=<?php echo date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n', strtotime($_GET['month'])) + 1, 1, $_GET['year'])); ?>

&year=<?php echo date("Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n', strtotime($_GET['month'])) + 1, 1, $_GET['year'])); ?>
```

Comment: Do you need to roll over the year as well?

Comment: date('F', 13) === "December"

Comment: Yes the year should roll over if it is Jan 2014 it should go to Dec 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code may work smoother for you. It makes use of the strtotime's ability to move the date forward or backward:

**Previous button**:

```
onclick="location.href='?view=list

&month=<?php echo date('F', strtotime($_GET['month'].' '.$_GET['year'].' -1 month')); ?>

&year=<?php echo date('Y', strtotime($_GET['month'].' '.$_GET['year'].' -1 month')); ?>
```

**Next button**:

```
onclick="location.href='?view=list

&month=<?php echo date('F', strtotime($_GET['month'].' '.$_GET['year'].' +1 month')); ?>

&year=<?php echo date('Y', strtotime($_GET['month'].' '.$_GET['year'].' +1 month')); ?>
```

Comment: You don't even need the `1` in the inner `strtotime()` Just using "Month Year" is sufficient.

Comment: And actually you don't even need to nest them. It should work with a single expression like `strtotime("March 2014 +1 month")`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that is a lot more straight forward